# Sharepoint Workflow not properly copying List Item

Tags: list, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow, person-or-group

I'm currently making use of SharePoint Foundation, due to this I have needed to create my own Approval Workflow for requisitions, for the most part this works fine, but I have a strange issue where sometimes items aren't correctly copied to another list.

Again due to limitations with the Foundation version, instead of being able to give different users permissions surrounding one list, I've needed to create three separate lists.

**The flow is as follow:**
So User A creates an Item in My Requisitions, this then needs copied across to Manager Approval and Finance Approval.

The requisition will first need to be approved by a Manager, then it can be actioned upon by Finance, this works fine for the most part, but sometimes when copying the list item the Manager Field isn't populated.

This is a problem as it means that when a Manager is going to their Pending List, they can't see the item as they should only see items Where Manager = [Me]

**My question is:**
Is there something quirky about the Copy List Item action that may stop this from happening correctly, such as updates elsewhere for example and is there a way to stop this, or should I try and manage it some other way, such as updating the item after the copy to ensure parity.

Answer (score 0):

Are user ids associated in this flow, what I mean is, if you are referencing user id, manager user id and any other user ids check if they are valid, you can trying tacing steps into the workflow history list. This would help. 
Copy List Item function should work fine for all items.
Also quickly check if the item fields have any special characters, on to which it is failing.

Comment: The Users ID's are all correct, and for testing purposes the user creating the item has selected themselves as the manager, the column is also of type Person and Group so they can only select users from SharePoint Groups directly so there shouldn't be any special characters either.

This isn't a constant issue, it's intermittent which is strange. 

Everything is also passed fine to the Finance list which happens at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried logging into a list?